# Science stack exchanges helping other science stack exchanges!

Tags: discussion

The Physics Meta promotes support for all Science sites on Stack Exchange, in [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites) post. The same meta post is now on several other science SE Meta sites.

The Astronomy SE is one of the sites that has benefited from this (and is currently still benefiting from this, if you look at the "Sites in Beta" section of that Meta post).

Let's give back to the younger science communities, now that we here at Astronomy have graduated out of the Commitment stage, and let's help some of the other sites in Beta, as they are doing for us.

Below is the post from the Physics Meta (now on several others too).

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Science proposals need your help! Consider committing to these, to make them successful & scientific:

See also the long list of [science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science?tab=progress) and [technology](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=progress) proposals on Area 51.

---

## Committers needed

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Synthetic Biology]

---

## Site definition needed

---

## Sites in beta

[Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science?tab=beta) and [technology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=beta) sites currently in beta include:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Materials Modeling]
[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Operations Research]
[image: Space]
[image: Robotics]
[image: Astronomy]
[image: Earth Science]
[image: Engineering]
[image: Mathematics Educators]
[image: Open Data]
[image]

---

This is community wiki -- feel free to add other proposals worth mentioning.